# How can I create a symbolic integer for use with my Fourier transform?

Tags: matlab, integer

I am computing a Fourier transformation in MATLAB, when computing coefficients `C[0]` and `C[n*f0]`, I got pretty nasty result because MATLAB doesn't recognize my variable "n" as integer. I currently compute with "n" as a symbolic variable (`syms n;`). How to change symbolic `n` to symbolic integer `n`?

Comment: Can you show some code? It'll help to help you.

Comment: I would live to, but my project is huge :-( it's not about code, however, there must be way how to say, that symbolic variable is integer... unfortunately, I wasn't able to find it

Comment: Can you at least post something that reproduces the error?

Comment: there is no error at all, I just want to have more simple result than now by declaring n as a symbolic integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [MATLAB documenation](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-1A4Q4/index.html?product=SM&solution=1-1A4Q4), to add the assumption "`n` is integer" in R2008b or later, you have to write

```
evalin(symengine,'assume(n,Type::Integer)')
```

**This answers your question, however, I'm not really sure it solves your problem.**

When you do a Fourier transform, you are performing a heavy numeric operation on your data, consequently all variables involved in that need to have concrete values. Your `n` probably should be an integer, but not just by type, it should contain an actual number. If you declare it using [`syms`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/symbolic/syms.html), it will potentially *not* contain a number, so you *be sure you really need the symbolic toolbox*!

If you do, and `n` is the result of a calculation that yield one specific integer, you can convert it to normal numerical form using `uint32(n)` or similar, see the [help on conversions](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/symbolic/f3-157665.html#f3-158993), e.g.

```
Y = fft(X,uint32(n))
```

*Update:* The error message you give in the comment implies that your `n` is in fact not an integer... I doubt you will be able to use it with fft.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I cannot convert it :-( it is giving me error:  DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double
array. But when I tried vpa(n), nothing happened

If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function
instead.

Comment: You have to write a short example code (maybe 5-10 lines) for us to show your exact problem - otherwise we can't help you...